# Create composite baseline via command line

Tags: clearcase

I must be missing something but not sure what.
Trying to replicate the function of the ClearProjExp steps to create project with a component and a composite baseline using the command line and scripts to automate out processes. ClearCase 8.0.0.3 / AIX.

Select New Project ...

- Step 1 of the Wizard: y_project_1.0, my_project_1.0_int, Traditional Parallel Dev, Next
- Step 2, seed the project from the selected mainline baseline, Next
- Step 3, add the component and the composite, remove other components, Next
- Step 4, make only component modifiable, Next
- Step 5, No ClearQuest Integration, Finish (we actually have CQ, int, but for this eg.)
- Continue

Project created

Select Project, Edit Baseline Dependencies ...

- Drag'n'drop component on composite, OK
- Base Name: BL0, OK

Composite baseline created.

I can create a project and a stream with one or more components using the command line, but am stumped adding the composite. I can't add a non-modifiable component to the project and I can't make the composite baseline because the composite is not in the project. What am I missing please?

```
cleartool mkproject
   -in myfolder@/vobs/Appplication_pvob
   -model DEFAULT
   -blname_template component,date,time,basename
   -policy ${POLICY}
   -npolicy ${NEG_POLCIY}
   -modcomp ComponentA, ComponentA_composite my_project_1.0@/vobs/Appplication_pvob

cleartool: Warning: Skipping component "ComponentA_composite".  This component stores only baselines, not file elements, and cannot be modified directly by users.

cleartool mkstream
   -integration
   -in my_project_1.0@/vobs/Appplication_pvob
   -baseline ComponentA_130626_011525_BL0.1 stream:my_project_1.0_int@/vobs/Appplication_pvob

cleartool mkbl
   -component ComponentA_composite@/vobs/Appplication_pvob
   -adep ComponentA@/vobs/Appplication_pvob
   -view ccadmin_my_project_1.0_int BL0

cleartool: Error: Cannot make baseline of component "ComponentA_composite" because it is not in the configuration of stream "my_project_1.0_int".
cleartool: Error: Unable to create baselines.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should:

- [create a rooltess component](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21257313) "`Component_A`" first
  `cleartool mkcomp -nroot ComponentA_composite@/vobs/Appplication_pvob` (you did that already)
- **Add the initial baseline of the composite (rootless) component directly in the right stream** (meaning you don't need to add it to the project: said project only records *modifiable* component)
  `cd /view/ccadmin_my_project_1.0_int
  cleartool rebase -bas ComponentA_composite_INITIAL`
- make a composite baseline:
  `cleartool mkbl -comp ComponentA_composite@/vobs/Appplication_pvob -adepends_on component:ComponentA@/vobs/Appplication_pvob -view ccadmin_my_project_1.0_int BL0`

That last part should work since the foundation baselines of the stream does include the rootless component `ComponentA_composite`.

Comment: As always, @VonC comes through! The rootles component had already been made (my omission). The indicated steps produce the correct end result but with a variation. If done via the GUI, there is no need to create a view to perform the rebase.